# quiero convertir un String a un Json y luego guardar un Json en ese String en Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, autenticación

```
     class AuthService{
       Future updateUserName(String nombre, String telefono,String apellido FirebaseUser user) async 
          { var userUpdateInfo = UserUpdateInfo(); userUpdateInfo.displayName = nombre;

              userUpdateInfo.photoUrl = //aqui podria almacenar esos datos extra
              await user.updateProfile(userUpdateInfo);
              await user.reload();
           }
       }
```

//Firebase tiene un conjunto fijo de propiedades de usuario que se pueden actualizar pero no agregar. //La idea que tengo es agregar pequeñas cantidades de datos extra como apellido y telefono con la ayuda //de la serialización y deserialización pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo recien empiezo en flutter

//luego almacenar esos datos extras en propiedades no utilizadas para almacenar la cadena //ya sea en DisplayName o en la propiedad photoURL. Se puede?

Answer (score 0):

Para pasar de `String` a `json` e inversamente utilizamos `dart:convert`

pasar de `String` a `json`

```
final mijson = json.decode(tuString);
```

pasar de `json` a `String`, que aquí me parece que seria mas pasar de `Map` a `String`

```
final miMap<String,dynamic> = {'Nombre':'Juan', 'id':2};

final miString = json.encode(miMap);
```